# Gutenberg: change block Components Popover properties

Tags: block-editor

I have added a custom button to an existing paragraph block toolbar using this:

```
const withToolbarButton = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        const { attributes, setAttributes } = props;
        const { paragraphAttribute } = attributes;

        return (
            <>
                <BlockControls>
                    <ToolbarButton
                        icon="smiley"
                        label={ __( 'Custom button' ) }
                        isActive={ paragraphAttribute === 'custom' }
                        onClick={ () => {
                            if ( paragraphAttribute === 'custom' ) {
                                setAttributes( { paragraphAttribute: false } );
                            } else {
                                setAttributes( {
                                    paragraphAttribute: 'custom',
                                } );
                            }
                        } }
                    />
                </BlockControls>
                <BlockEdit { ...props } />
            </>
        );
    };
}, 'withToolbarButton' );
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'editor.BlockEdit',
    'custom-attributes/with-toolbar-button',
    withToolbarButton
);
```

How do change properties (add CSS class or change positioning) of the Components Popover (to which this button belongs)?
So for example, if the button is clicked I want to change the position of the popover.

[image]